# Autohotkey cannot Undo a Capslock

Tags: autohotkey, windows-xp-sp3

For some reason, <kbd>Capslock</kbd> cannot be undone in AHK.
E.G: This will not turn `On` *and* `Off` <kbd>Capslock</kbd>.

```
loop:
Send {CapsLock}
Sleep 500
goto loop
```

It will be stuck on.
<strike>Can someone help me out here?</strike>

Thx, FXAM.
Here is what I did:

```
SetStoreCapslockMode, Off
haha:
Send {NumLock}
Sleep 500
Send {NumLock}{CapsLock}
Sleep 500
Send {CapsLock}{ScrollLock}
Sleep 500
Send {ScrollLock}
goto haha
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting [SetStoreCapslockMode](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetStoreCapslockMode.htm) to Off before starting the fun!

```
SetStoreCapslockMode, Off
loop:
    Send {CapsLock}
    Sleep 500
goto loop
```

Another way by using [SetCapsLockState](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetNumScrollCapsLockState.htm)

```
ToggleCapslock() {
    local flag := false
    loop:
        if (flag) {
            SetCapsLockState, On
        } else {
            SetCapsLockState, Off
        }
        flag := !flag
        Sleep 500
    goto loop
}
```

Comment: An explanation and/or link to the [docs](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetStoreCapslockMode.htm) would improve this answer (+1 though, works for me)

Comment: @Blorgbeard: I have difficulty in explaining this so a link is provided: )

Comment: @Blorgbeard documentation at autohotkey.com is outdated. Most updated documentation is here: http://ahkscript.org/docs/AutoHotkey.htm